# How to get html page path in a django project?

Tags: python, html, regex, django

My role is to reconstruct html & css in a django project which contains 10 apps.
each app has a urls.py file.
And the urls to the .html is written in a very complicated way like this:

```
url(r'^\w+/.*list/(?P<objtype>[\.\w-]+)/(?P<parent_str>(((\w+)/)*))$', utilreqs.listview)
```

Is there a way to know the path to which html page I'm viewing in the browser?
ex: projectname/appname/templates/name.html

Comment: The `url` page directs you to the view, not the HTML template. You will have to look at the `utilreqs.listview` file to determine the template used.

Comment: I am not sure where you want to access this information, but if you have a `request` object, you can access the `.path` attribute. For example, in a template `{{ request.path }}` would display the path to that html template.

Comment: @elethan the {{ request.path }} displays the same path on the address bar, but it doesn't show the html path.
ex: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/superss/
it show on html page : accounts/superss.... whereas the html file path is templates/sign_in.html

Comment: Now I understand. In that case @brianpck is right: you need to look at the `utilreqs.listview` view function and see which template it renders.

Comment: Note also that if you install Django Debug Toolbar, you can see the templates being rendered when you visit the page in the browser.